# Como criar campos BLOB SQLITE com delphi

Tags: delphi, sqlite

Estou a desenvolver uma APP para android através do delphi. 
recentemente tenho tentado criar um campo do tipo BLOB na minha base de dados SQLITE  no entato quando faço

```
ShowMessage(query.FieldByName('imagem').ClassName);
```

(peço o tipo de dados do campo) retorna me como TLongIntField

estou a criar a tabela assim:

```
Gia_1C.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artigos (codigo_arm TEXT, Referencia TEXT PRIMARY KEY, designacao1 TEXT , preco1 TEXT, Imagem  BLOB);');
```

Comment: Qual a versão do seu SQLITE ?

Comment: procurei nos ficheiros de instalação do delphi mas não encontrei la nada. Na internet só encontro artigos relacionados com exemplos de operações com SQLITE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema. antes tinha o metodo de inserção da seguinte maneira:

```
procedure Tform33.Insert_data_ART;
var i:integer;
     sql:string;
     ms:TStream;
     blopfield:Tfield;
begin
 ShowMessage(inttostr(num_regs_fb_ART));
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  for I := 1 to num_regs_fb_ART do
           begin
            try
              Artigos_imgTable.Active:=false;
              Artigos_imgTable.Close;

              sql:= ('INSERT INTO Artigos_img (Codigo_arm,Referencia,Designacao1,'+
                     'preco1,imagem) ' +
                     'VALUES' +
                     ' (''' + Codigo_arm[i] + ''', ' +
                     '''' +Referencia[i] + ''', ' +
                     '''' + Designacao1[i] + ''', ' +
                     '' + preco1[i] + ');' );

            Artigos_imgTable.CommandText:=sql;
             ms.Position:=0;
             try
                Artigos_imgTable.active:=true;
                  with Artigos_imgTable do
                     begin
                     Insert;
                     blopfield:=FieldByName('imagem');
                     ms:=CreateBlobStream(blopfield,bmWrite);
                     BinaryAsBITMap[I].SaveToStream(ms);
                     end;
                except
                on e:exception do
                infotext(e.Message);
              end;
              try
              Artigos_imgTable.CommandText:=sql;
              Artigos_imgTable.ExecSQL(true);
              except on E: Exception do
              ShowMessage(e.message);
              end;
             finally
             ms.Free;
            end;
         end;
      infoText('Dados Atualizados...');
end;
```

Entao como é do tipo BLOB como o primeiro dado que entra é um 0 ou um 1 e como o SQLite molda o tipo do campo ao tipo de dado que entra, A base de dados assumia que eu estava a inserir um long int.

A correta maneira de inserção de um BLOB é da seguinte maneira:

```
procedure Tform33.Insert_data_ART;
var i:integer;
     sql:string;
     ms:TStream;
     LTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
     LParams: TParams;

begin
  for I := 1 to num_regs_fb_ART do
           begin
                  sql:= ('INSERT INTO Artigos (Codigo_arm,Referencia,Designacao1,'+
                     'preco1,Imagem) ' +
                     'VALUES' +
                     ' (''' + Codigo_arm[i] + ''', ' +
                     '''' +Referencia[i] + ''', ' +
                     '''' + Designacao1[i] + ''', ' +
                     '''' + preco1[i] + ''', ' +
                      ':Imagem)' );
            try

            LTransaction:=Gia_1C.BeginTransaction;
            LParams:=TParams.Create(nil);
            ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
            BinaryAsBITMap[I].SaveToStream(ms);
              try
                LParams.CreateParam(ftBlob,'Imagem',ptinput);
                LParams.ParamByName('Imagem').LoadFromStream(ms,ftblob);
                Gia_1C.Execute(SQL,Lparams);
                Gia_1C.CommitFreeAndNil(LTransaction);
              finally
                FreeAndNil(ms);
                FreeAndNil(Lparams);
              end;
             except on E: Exception do
              infoText(e.Message);
            end;
         end;
      infoText('Dados Atualizados...');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

para pegar o tipo do campo utilize:

```
 query.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType
```

e o Delphi nao retorna o data type como estamos acostumados (String / varchar, inteiro, float, etc). Você terá que verificar como esta vindo pelo tipo blob

Quando preciso realizar este procedimento faço da seguinte forma:

```
if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType in [ftString, ftwideString, ftWideMemo] then
   begin
      data_tyoe := 'String';
      tamanho := qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].Size;
   end
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftBoolean then
        data_tyoe := 'Boolean'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType in [ftFloat, ftcurrency] then
        data_tyoe := 'Float'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType in [ftDateTime,ftTimeStamp] then
        data_tyoe := 'DateTime'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftDate then
        data_tyoe := 'Date'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftTime then
        data_tyoe := 'Time'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType in [ftAutoInc, ftInteger, ftSmallInt] then
        data_tyoe := 'Integer'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftMemo then
        data_tyoe := 'Text'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftsingle then
        data_tyoe := 'Real'
else if qryBuscaCampos.FieldList.Fields[nro_campo].DataType = ftBCD then
        data_tyoe := 'Numeric';
```

Como alguns datatype variam conforme o SGBD utilizado recomendo vc colocar esse codigo em um comando de repetição ate identificar o datatype correto para o seu campo blob

Obs: o nro_campo deve comçar em 0

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo eu experimentei da maneira como referiu mas o tipo de dados continua como LongInt, creio que tem a ver com o metodo de inserção de dados. 
Li algures que o SQlite molda o tipo de dados de um campo de acordo com oque recebe, oque torna-se uma faca de dois gumes.
Meu problema agora é outro. devo eliminar a minha pergunta?

Comment: na verdade esta certo pois como o delphi trata o campo eh indiferente, campo blob é binario ou seja somente 0 e 1 ou seja vai ser um longint no final das contas. Mas e agora qual seria seu problema?

Comment: Eu creio que encontrei o problema. O erro encontrava-se no metodo que eu estava a utilizar para inserir o BLOB na base de dados. Dentro de momentos adicionarei a solução aqui. Obrigado.